# Copying files between /shares?

Tags: linux, nfs, smb, nas

I have this Seagate NAS with SSH enabled, I need to copy all data from shares to one share and then zip it, so let's say it looks like this:

```
Share 1
Share 2
Share 3 -> Share backup 
Share 5
Share 6
```

If I mount it, it'll take a lot of time since the transfer will go between the shares and not the physical hard drives.

I tried to do this with FTP, but didn't work.

I tried to do this with SSH and

`cp share1/* backupshare/share1`

but didn't work. I also tried to do it using the webgui but that didn't work neither because something is wrong with the firmware. It's around 12TB of data.  What can I try next ?

Update:

first I tried

```
cp * ../backupshare/sharebackup1
```

but then it just said "Ommiting directory" and all the directories and it was finished in around 1 second, but then I used

```
sudo cp -R * ../backupshare/share1
```

and then it doesn't give any output at all and seems like it's freezing but I'm not sure though.

Also, the nas is running RAID 5 I think.

Comment: can you explain what went wrong when you used ssh ? what error message did you get ?

Comment: @XTian first I tried cp * ../backupshare/sharebackup1 but then it just said "Ommiting directory" and all the directories and it was finished in around 1 second, but then I used sudo cp -R * ../backupshare/share1 and then it doesn't give any output at all and seems like it's freezing but I'm not sure though. And also, the nas is running RAID 5 I think.

Comment: Please add your further explation to the original question, this makes it easier to read (I did it for you this time). `cp` has a `-v` option so that you can see progress as it copies did you take a look at `../backupshare/share1` after breaking out of the copy ? if you are moving within a filesystem then `mv` will move files and directories, but try it first on a test dir until you are confident with the command.

Comment: In order to distinguish hours of busily copying files from freezing, how about you copy (I suggest `cp -pr source dest`) a small directory over first, then tell us what happened?